# Ant task for jar

Tags: java, ant

Compiling works fine, but it's not packaging into a jar file.
The final message is BUILD SUCCESSFUL with compiled classes but I cannot find a  jar.

```
<project name="thisIsMyProject" basedir="." default="build">
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
     Load Classpath and such.....
    .
    .
    .
    . 

   <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="my.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <mkdir dir="build"/>
    <target name="jar" description="Make My Jar File" depends="init">
        <jar destfile="myFile.jar" destdir="build" basedir="bin" compress="true" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Did you try running ant with -verbose?

Comment: Tried -verbose. It doesn't hint anything either. BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your target names are wrong.

Your default target is "build", but you don't actually have a target called "build" - perhaps you should change the default to "jar"

Your "jar" target depends on "init", but it should probably also depend on "build-project" if you want it to compile BEFORE it packages the jar.

Comment: Tried half of your solution - changed default to jar. Same result. Added build-project as dependency as well. No luck. This is really really weird.

Comment: you also have a <mkdir> which isn't inside a target - this is a bit weird, and possibly a cause of problems, try moving the mkdir inside the "jar" target

Comment: Ok I moved it inside and it didnt create a new directory. This at least proves it's not only going in there.

Comment: there still seems to be something very strange about your targets - perhaps it's worth posting the whole build.xml. Also - how do you run ant?

Comment: I am running within Eclipse. Run As - Ant